# Hidlibrary only reports zeros continiously

Tags: c#

device keeps reporting 00, 00, 00, 00 non stop, not one device I tried has reported correct bytes it's just zeros or silence. What can I do? I'm trying to catch a mouse non standard button click, USBlyzer says it sends 80 00 00 00, but only zeros here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HidLibrary;

namespace MouseHandler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /*private const int VendorId = 0x09DA;
        private const int ProductId = 0x000A;
        private const int VendorId = 0x046D;
        private const int ProductId = 0xC52B;*/
        private const int VendorId = 0x0D8C;
        private const int ProductId = 0x013C;

        private static HidDevice device;
        bool paused = false;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (device != null)
            {
                device.OpenDevice();
                device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;
                device.ReadReport(rreport);
            }
        }
        private void rreport(HidReport report)
        {
            if (!paused)
            {
                write(string.Join(", ", report.Data.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
                device.ReadReport(rreport);
            }
        }
        void write(string text)
        {
            if (ControlInvokeRequired(textBox1, () => write(text))) return;
            textBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        public bool ControlInvokeRequired(Control c, Action a)
        {
            if (c.InvokeRequired) c.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { a(); }));
            else return false;

            return true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            paused = !paused;
            device.ReadReport(rreport);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the report.Data structure with a debugger? Is this array really contains zeros? In case you really receive zeros that it possibly may be HidLibrary issue with your device model. The support for this library is very limited since the amount of possible devices configurations is enormous.  Probably than you will need to write your own low level filter driver.

Comment: @VitaliyK Yeah it's just zeros http://i.imgur.com/XaapNdL.png I Think it's my fault still, cause none of the devices I tried worked. If you're familiar with hidlibrary do you think anything in my code could cause this?

Comment: Previously on one of my projects we have the same issues with  devices and HidLibrary  - it just not working in a lots of situations. So we created a low level  driver to get the reports. You could also check  different events on device - like Inserted or Removed etc. if they are working. In the end you could download sources from GitHub and debug the library manually. From the part of your code - everything looks simple and fine.